# Get a child element from document

Tags: c#, json, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to get a child element from my document using the c# connector.

My document looks something like this:

```
// sample document
{
   "_id":
   {
      "$oid":"myid"
   },
   "Somedata":"This is a test",
   "object1":
   {
      "name":"myname",
      "object2":
      {
         "Text":"Hello World!"
      }
   }
}
```

I have a class that maps on to this, that looks something like the following:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class MyDataClass
{
    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("object1.object2.Text")]
    public string Text;
    [BsonElement("Somedata")]
    public string Data;
}
```

When the query runs, the id and Data variables are populated, but the Text variable is not. My guess is that this is because it is inside an object, but I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Comment: I believe your _id is in a wrong format, are you sure the _id is {
      "$oid":"myid"
   }

Comment: When mongodb returns a document it returns whole document. There is no column name specific selection like we can in SQL. So you need to iterate through Object1 to get the text field. I believe mongodb driver wont do that for you

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BsonElement` accept a parameter as name for root-level of field name such as **'field1'**, and you cant pass a nested name (using dot notation naming such as **'field1.nested_field'**). You have to define some classes for your sub documents

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
    public string Somedata { get; set; }
    public Object1 object1 { get; set; }
}

public class Object1
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Object2 object2 { get; set; }
}

public class Object2
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

And if don't want to define new classes for your sub-documents, you have to write your own mongo `Serializer` and `DeSerializer` for `MyDataClass`